# juno neutron with gre tunnel, qrouter not pinging vm and vm not getting ip from dhcp

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

I have 3 node architecture of openstack juno setup.

Everything working fine on controller and compute. VM getting created and all.

But seems my Network node and Compute node have some issue over data network as VM is not taking IP from DHCP. Also when i checked and assigned IP to vm manually, it is pinging gateway but qrouter not pinging VM instance.

qrouter is configured correctly and tenant network is attached to it. qrouter is also pinging tenant network default gateway as its only its one of the interface.

Help me guys I am stuck here don't know what to do. Putting some command output for detail:

```
[root@network ~]# ip netns show
qdhcp-ade4d591-6016-4a11-8e07-6718340d673e
qrouter-99ed72a2-b69c-41f8-854e-4c6c8448f50d

[root@network ~]# ovs-vsctl show
c6e9b29e-9dac-4e74-a31a-c8cba6a8c977
Bridge br-tun
    fail_mode: secure
    Port patch-int
        Interface patch-int
            type: patch
            options: {peer=patch-tun}
    Port "gre-0a00011f"
        Interface "gre-0a00011f"
            type: gre
            options: {df_default="true", in_key=flow, local_ip="10.0.1.21", out_key=flow, remote_ip="10.0.1.31"}
    Port br-tun
        Interface br-tun
            type: internal
Bridge br-int
    fail_mode: secure
    Port int-br-ex
        Interface int-br-ex
            type: patch
            options: {peer=phy-br-ex}
    Port "tap1c21fba3-49"
        tag: 1
        Interface "tap1c21fba3-49"
            type: internal
    Port "qr-d8ce18d8-96"
        tag: 1
        Interface "qr-d8ce18d8-96"
            type: internal
    Port patch-tun
        Interface patch-tun
            type: patch
            options: {peer=patch-int}
    Port br-int
        Interface br-int
            type: internal
Bridge br-ex
    Port br-ex
        Interface br-ex
            type: internal
    Port phy-br-ex
        Interface phy-br-ex
            type: patch
            options: {peer=int-br-ex}
    Port "eth1"
        Interface "eth1"
    Port "qg-3a032814-ae"
        Interface "qg-3a032814-ae"
            type: internal
ovs_version: "2.3.1"

[root@network ~]# ip netns exec qrouter-99ed72a2-b69c-41f8-854e-4c6c8448f50d iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Sep  2 11:16:12 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [9733:4197036]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
 :OUTPUT ACCEPT [34:2617]
:neutron-filter-top - [0:0]
:neutron-l3-agent-FORWARD - [0:0]
:neutron-l3-agent-INPUT - [0:0]
:neutron-l3-agent-OUTPUT - [0:0]
:neutron-l3-agent-local - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j neutron-l3-agent-INPUT
-A FORWARD -j neutron-filter-top
-A FORWARD -j neutron-l3-agent-FORWARD
-A OUTPUT -j neutron-filter-top
-A OUTPUT -j neutron-l3-agent-OUTPUT
-A neutron-filter-top -j neutron-l3-agent-local
-A neutron-l3-agent-INPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9697 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Sep  2 11:16:12 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Sep  2 11:16:12 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [7984:630587]
:INPUT ACCEPT [173:20642]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [16:1201]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [12:865]
:neutron-l3-agent-OUTPUT - [0:0]
:neutron-l3-agent-POSTROUTING - [0:0]
:neutron-l3-agent-PREROUTING - [0:0]
:neutron-l3-agent-float-snat - [0:0]
:neutron-l3-agent-snat - [0:0]
:neutron-postrouting-bottom - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j neutron-l3-agent-PREROUTING
-A OUTPUT -j neutron-l3-agent-OUTPUT
-A POSTROUTING -j neutron-l3-agent-POSTROUTING
-A POSTROUTING -j neutron-postrouting-bottom
-A neutron-l3-agent-POSTROUTING ! -i qg-3a032814-ae ! -o qg-3a032814-ae -m conntrack ! --ctstate DNAT -j ACCEPT
-A neutron-l3-agent-PREROUTING -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9697
-A neutron-l3-agent-snat -j neutron-l3-agent-float-snat
-A neutron-l3-agent-snat -s 192.168.10.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 135.249.88.101
-A neutron-postrouting-bottom -j neutron-l3-agent-snat
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Sep  2 11:16:12 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Sep  2 11:16:12 2015
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [17544:4806981]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [34:2617]
:neutron-l3-agent-OUTPUT - [0:0]
:neutron-l3-agent-PREROUTING - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j neutron-l3-agent-PREROUTING
-A OUTPUT -j neutron-l3-agent-OUTPUT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Sep  2 11:16:12 2015
```

On compute Node

```
[root@compute1 ~]# ovs-vsctl show
491cdefe-00ef-46ad-b4a8-5b57ac630968
Bridge br-int
    fail_mode: secure
    Port "qvoc4e1f1c6-dd"
        tag: 1
        Interface "qvoc4e1f1c6-dd"
    Port br-int
        Interface br-int
            type: internal
    Port patch-tun
        Interface patch-tun
            type: patch
            options: {peer=patch-int}
Bridge br-tun
    fail_mode: secure
    Port br-tun
        Interface br-tun
            type: internal
    Port "gre-0a000115"
        Interface "gre-0a000115"
            type: gre
            options: {df_default="true", in_key=flow, local_ip="10.0.1.31", out_key=flow, remote_ip="10.0.1.21"}
    Port patch-int
        Interface patch-int
            type: patch
            options: {peer=patch-tun}
ovs_version: "2.3.1"
```

Let me know if any other details required.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer : there is no issue in the configuration and everything is fine. The only problem is that rules on `security group :- default.`

The default security group rule do not allow you to ping vm from qrouter or qdhcp.

So the solution is that either you have to add another security group for your project with appropriate rules or add rules to default security group.

I have added below two rules for accessibility:

```
Ingress IPv4    ICMP    -   0.0.0.0/0 (CIDR)
Egress  IPv4    ICMP    -   0.0.0.0/0 (CIDR)
```

That solve my problem and now I am able to reach VM from qrouter.